# UWP: Can't create a new VPN profile

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to create a new VPN profile in a universal windows app. 
I am using [this api.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn)

There are two documented ways to do that. AddProfileFromXmlAsync and AddProfileFromObjectAsync. Unfortunately for me none of them work correctly.

When I'm using AddProfileFromXmlAsync I get all the time error AccessDenied. I saw on this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43b8e1ce-bd23-4d0e-8295-00bacb50098d/can-not-create-vpn-profile-using-addprofilefromxmlasync?forum=wpdevelop) that somehow it could be related to bad xml syntax but I get the same error also when I am using the exact [xml in the Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/vpnv2-csp#examples).

AddProfileFromObjectAsync works fine if you provide only the ProfileName. Otherwise it fails with error Other. This is not enough for me because I need also the configure the NativeProtocolType property. Before I am trying to add the new profile I am checking to see if the profile already exists so for sure I am not getting error Other because the profile already exists.

I am adding these capabilities to my app manifest:

```
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
        <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
       <rescap:Capability Name="networkingVpnProvider" />
  </Capabilities>
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working sample atleast on 15063 (Note that there was a bug in the Anniversary update which was causing the API not to work so either try with 15063 or make sure you have all the updates on the Aniversary update)

```
// Install key and cert
await 
CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(PEMKey,
Password,
ExportOption.NotExportable,
KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
InstallOptions.None,
"Test VPN");

VpnNativeProfile profile = new VpnNativeProfile();
profile.AlwaysOn = true;
profile.NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.IpsecIkev2;
profile.ProfileName = "Test VPN";
profile.RememberCredentials = false;
profile.RequireVpnClientAppUI = true;
profile.RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.ForceAllTrafficOverVpn;
profile.Servers.Add(Constants.ConcentratorDNSName);
profile.UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap;
profile.EapConfiguration = File.ReadAllText("profile.xml");
VpnManagementAgent agent = new VpnManagementAgent();
await agent.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
VpnManagementErrorStatus status = await agent.ConnectProfileAsync(profile);
```

Sample EAP XML configuration can be found @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/eap-configuration

Also Unfortunately the the XML in the VPNv2 CSP is different from the one in the API. Additionally on checking internally at Microsoft there seems to be a bug with the AddProfileFromXMLAsync causing it not to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aman!
I tried you example and it works for creating a profile but I can't connect using a user name and password.

vpnAgent.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(connectionProfile, new PasswordCredential
            {
                UserName = "userName",
                Password = "password"
            });

I get error Other.

Comment: Works now. The issue was that after creating the profile I was enumerating all the profiles with GetProfilesAsync and then after I was finding my newly created profile I was calling ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync with user name and password. For some reason it doesn't work. The returned error was Other but the real error in Event Viewer is 87 (invalid param). It seems that ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync works only if you create a new VpnNativeProfile profile (I think this is a bug). In the end I am creating on every connect the profile and on disconnect I'm deleting it.

Comment: Great, and you are able to see the VPN connection in Windows 10 UI?

Comment: Yes, it is visible in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and also in Settings -> Network & Internet -> VPN (Metro App).

Comment: i am also getting the same error Other..
what should i do please let me know thanks..
how to check that the profile is already created or not...

Comment: and please let me know how you enter username and password for the vpn